# SQL select one or the other value from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that has two columns. The first column contains the id of a person record that matches the id of the person record in the second column (from the same system)  i.e. they are duplicates. The code that loads the table ensures that the id in each column will only be in the column once, i.e.the id's are distinct in each column.  I show the data in an every other row order but that may not be the case in the actual table.

basically the process matches the data from 123 to the data of 456 and of course then matches the data of 456 to the data of 123 etc.

```
1. 123    456
2. 456    123
3. 678    910
4. 910    678
5. abc    def
6. def    abc
```

etc.

I need to delete either 123 or 456 but not both the same for 678 and 910 and abc and def etc. For example I need to select from the first column 123, 678, abc, etc. is this possible?

Note: The actual IDs are GUIDs but for simplicity I used simple numbers.

Comment: your question is unclear. You could do `delete from table where col1 < col2`

Comment: @vkp That would delete valid records as well. The sample data doesn't show it but it is likely to have records that do not result in a loop.

Comment: Daniel, if you are absolutely sure that the largest chain is 2 records, then you can join the table to itself where column 1 matches column 2 and then use the where clause @vkp suggested. If you are not sure how many records can form a loop, you will need to use a recursive CTE to identify the potential loops.

Comment: thanks, yes the largest chain is 2 records

Comment: Not sure why this is on hold its been answered and solved by MikeD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, see if this SELECT satisfies your needs, then replace `SELECT ...` by `DELETE FROM`

```
SELECT id1, id2 FROM Test as t1
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 'X' FROM Test as t2
   WHERE  t2.id1 = t1.id2
   AND    t2.id2 = t1.id1
   AND    t2.id1 < t2.id2
   )
```

We're looking for all pairing records, but finally use/delete the one where the higher id is in first column.

Comment: this worked Thanks!   DELETE FROM Test where id1 in (SELECT id1, id2 FROM Test as t1
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 'X' FROM Test as t2
   WHERE  t2.id1 = t1.id2
   AND    t2.id2 = t1.id1
   AND    t2.id1 < t2.id2
   ))

Comment: @MikeD where did you get the fieldnames id1 and id2 from?

Comment: I created a table `Test` in MySQL on my local host with 2 `VARCHAR(3)` fields named `id1` and `id2` ... inserted the OP's sample data and run the SQL statement against this table to verify my solution is correct

Comment: @DanielRusch you can shorten yours to ` DELETE FROM Test as t1 WHERE EXISTS (...)` ... secondly it's goot practice to exactly match parameters in `IN` subqueries ... e.g. `id1 IN (SELECT id1 FROM ...)`

Comment: Sorry there is an error in my comment above  there can't be id2 in the SELECT:  DELETE FROM Test where id1 in (SELECT id1 FROM Test as t1 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'X' FROM Test as t2 WHERE t2.id1 = t1.id2 AND t2.id2 = t1.id1 AND t2.id1 < t2.id2 ))    I tried DELETE FROM Test as t1 WHERE EXISTS (..) but SQL Server thew and error. I only need to  run this once on the initial load so if its a little slow or inelegant that's ok :)